# How to improve / enhance this regex expression to highlight this 3 different lines

Tags: regex

I would like to highlight this 3 different lines in my document

```
A552646743MYS210824-3M2609223215303««««62 
E.163879383CHNO211026 m 3 20905511BP Ftlfvlfv1GLP' 
A 56 2 3004 40MYS5910070 F27111 2859100705 5264<<68
```

I am currently using this regex expression

```
^[A-Z0-9<]{9}.*[A-Z].*
```

am improve to this

```
[A-Z0-9]{1}(\s|[A-Z0-9.<]*){8}[A-Z0-9]{1}[A-Z]{3}[A-Z0-9]{6}[A-Z0-9]{1}.*
```

however this only limit to some of the string highlight

Comment: What are the rules for the pattern?

Comment: Add a few other examples of valid data and put some extra lines that you don't want to match so that we see what you have. We can't help you if you cannot explain us what is the format of the searched lines. By the way, `[A-Z0-9]{1}` can simply be written `[A-Z0-9]` or `[A-Z\d]` as you only want one occurrence of the character class. I also don't understand the `{8}` after the first alternative group because you should not be matching 8 spaces. I don't see any `<` char either in the first part of your lines 